# No android/unityLibrary/libs/VuforiaWrapper.aar exist + embedded Unity (Vuforia) into flutter

Tags: android, flutter, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm tyring to embedded Unity (Vuforia) within flutter, I follwo the same steps here https://github.com/juicycleff/flutter-unity-view-widget .

at step 9 I had an issue : (No android/unityLibrary/libs/VuforiaWrapper.aar exist)

uityEditor : 2022.2.0

I used FlutterUnityIntegration-v4.1.0 and fuw-2022.2.0 insaid unity project.

after the exsport unityLibrary into flutter there is No VuforiaWrapper.aar.

I searched many sources and did not find the answer.
Any help will be highly appreciated !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recently made Flutter vuforia project and I didn't have any problems, I will tell you the steps of making it

1-create flutter app

2-in flutterProject create unity folder

3-in unity hub create project inside unity folder in flutterProject

4-add **add-vuforia-package-10-9-3** to unity project

5-add **fuw-2022.1.7f1** to unity project

6-copy **fuw-2022.1.7f1** and paste in flutterProject/unity/yourUnityProject

7-add your vuforia license key

8-go to player setting Android/other setting of android and set like images

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

came back to flutter project

9-add ndk.dir to local.properties

10-add

**include ":unityLibrary"**

**project(":unityLibrary").projectDir = file("./unityLibrary")**

in **android/settings.gradle**

11-add **implementation project(':unityLibrary')** to dependencies in **android/app/build.gradle**

12-change minSdkVersion to 21

13-go back to unity project and on top click flutter/Export Android (relesase)

14-run flutter ...

thats it enjoy your project